# Show custom fields in products loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've added custom products fields with this tutorial http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/

Now i need to show them in the products loop like shown in the image below

[image: product loop display]

The left part are table headings with the custom field names, on the rigs side are products with up to 4 products on one page (the client doesn't want more).

I'm stuck on the product loop display here, got the procuct variations to show on category page with the ability to add to cart, but can't wrap my head around this task so any advice how to show this would be appreciated

Comment: All you need to know is at the bottom of that tutorial.. "Retrieve Fields Values". All you need to do is markup the layout and echo the fields where they need to go.

Comment: Maybe i didn't write the question right, my problem is where to put the Retrieve Fields Values code into the loop to have the layout in the image.

Comment: Add a new directory in your theme folder called woocommerce (files that you change in this folder overwrites woocommerce files, that way you can update woocommerce safely). Find the directory `templates` inside the woocommerce plugin directory and copy the `single-product` directory and `content-single-product.php` file. that's where the content of the single product goes.

Comment: OK i think I've got it. Thanks